# GLFW and GLEW - Missing .libs

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I've not been having the best day today. I am completely new to opengl and c++ libraries in general. I don't know how to link the libraries to MSVS2015, so I decide to look up a tutorial on how to link the opengl libraries GLFW and GLEW.

I've read over 6 different tutorials over the last 8 hours, and they all tell me to link something to the "lib" folder. This folder is empty in the GLEW 2.0.0 download, and is completely missing in the GLFW 3.2.1 download.

Confused, I read online that there are supposed to be some .lib files in there. So I then searched both downloads for "*.lib", thinking they could have been moved in an update and found nothing with a ".lib" extension. I did the same with ".dll" and nothing was found.

I'm downloading these libraries from:

http://www.glfw.org/

http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Am I downloading it from the wrong source or were the tutorials just too old(The tutorials I found always stated that the latest versions were GLEW <1.9 and GLFW ~2)? If you need any more information(setup, pictures...) just ask.

Comment: Did you download the correct files? http://www.glfw.org/download.html You need the _Windows pre-compiled binaries_ download to get the precompiled lib files. For Glew the same, the _Binaries Windows 32-bit and 64-bit_ package is what you need.

Comment: How about trying this : https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/downloads/OpenGL_Extensions_Tutorial.zip  This includes references to GLEW and FREEGLUT in case you are only trying to explore them.

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid. I'm sorry about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to download the binaries for my system instead of the source, or build it with CMake or some other building program. Oh well, guess I learned :/